# Is there anyway I can cast the audio of my xbox one to a google chromecast audio?

Tags: xbox-one, audio-hardware

I have a projector that I use as my display for my xbox one. Unfortunately it only only has an audio in port.

Is there anyway I can send the audio from my xbox to my chromecast audio to then play through my speakers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of a way off hand. The Xbox One does have an optical audio port - maybe you can use that somehow?

Comment: Didn't we have another question like this, like a month ago, that was closed?

Comment: What are your speakers connected to?

Comment: @Adeese The speakers have an aux male. I was wondering if I could use a optical audio output to jack and then direct the audio to the speakers, then send the display through the hdmi...

Comment: @cwiggo Maybe something like this would work? https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=10251

Comment: Damn dude, if you invested in a proper projector setup (I hope you have a legit screen and not a white sheet), you should equally invest in even a basic stereo setup. Hell, even a sound bar! Xbone has SPDIF out and I think almost all sound bars have optical in.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the audio out from your Xbox one to SPDIF, then using an adapter convert that to a phono audio signal. It's the setup I have, it works fine.

So HDMI carries video to projector,
SPDIF carries audio separately straight to the speakers.